# how to toast message when radiobutton is clicked

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

I'm developing a quiz where I have 50 questions randomly displayed and 3 options (radiobuttons) and I'm using json array for storing the questions. My problem is how to display a toast message after the user clicked the radiobutton (one of the options) telling the user that he/she is wrong or correct. Please help me on how to achieve that.

Thank you so much. Help is really appreciated!

This is my code:

```
private void showQuestion(int qIndex, boolean review) {
    try {
        JSONObject aQues = Question1.getQuesList().getJSONObject(
                qIndex);
        String quesValue = aQues.getString("Question");
        if (correctAns[qIndex] == -1) {
            String correctAnsStr = aQues.getString("CorrectAnswer");
            correctAns[qIndex] = Integer.parseInt(correctAnsStr);
        }

        question.setText(quesValue.toCharArray(), 0, quesValue.length());
        answers.check(-1);
        answer1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        answer2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        answer3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        JSONArray ansList = aQues.getJSONArray("Answers");
        String aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(0).getString("Answer");
        answer1.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(1).getString("Answer");
        answer2.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(2).getString("Answer");
        answer3.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        Log.d("", selected[qIndex] + "");
        if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
            answers.check(R.id.option1);
        if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
            answers.check(R.id.option2);
        if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
            answers.check(R.id.option3);

        setText();
        if (quesIndex == (Question1.getQuesList().length() - 1))
            next.setEnabled(false);

        if (quesIndex < (Question1.getQuesList().length() - 1))
            next.setEnabled(true);

        if (review) {
            Log.d("review", selected[qIndex] + "" + correctAns[qIndex]);

            if (selected[qIndex] != correctAns[qIndex]) {
                if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                    answer1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                    answer2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                    answer3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 0)
                answer1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 1)
                answer2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 2)
                answer3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}


private void setAnswer() {
    if (answer1.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 0;
    if (answer2.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 1;
    if (answer3.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 2;



    Log.d("", Arrays.toString(selected));
    Log.d("", Arrays.toString(correctAns));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);        
    mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // check if the answer is right or wrong and Toast accordingly
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            //check the answer value corresponding to the checkedId RadioButton
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "...." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```